# Derivative of an entire function of finite order

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, entire-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function of order $\rho$, that is, $\rho$ is the least positive real so that there are constants $x,y$ with $|f(z)| \leq xe^{y|z|^\rho}$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I would like to show that the derivative $f'(z)$ is of finite order $\rho' \leq \rho$.

My attempt: Since $f$ is entire, it is analytic, so we can write
$$f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0}a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

$$f'(z) = \sum_{n \geq 1}na_n(z-z_0)^{n-1} = \sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)a_{n+1}(z-z_0)^n$$
Then using Cauchy estimates for the coefficients of $f'$,
$$(n+1)|a_{n+1}| \leq \int_0^{2\pi}|f'(z_0+e^{i\theta})|\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}$$
My idea was to integrate the RHS to get a function involving only $f$, and use $\rho$ to put a bound on the coefficients of $f'$. I am having trouble proceeding. How might I approach this problem?

Comment: First of all your definition  of order is not quite correct as the inequality above may not hold for $\rho$ (see $1/\Gamma$ which is order $1$ but there is no $y$ for which  the inequality  holds for $\rho=1$); second, do you know how to express order in terms of coefficients? There is a formula somewhat similar to the one giving the radius of convergence and from that it is immediate  that $f'$ has same order as $f$; however if not, for $|z|=R$ just apply cauchy on the circle of radius $2R$ to estimate $\max |f'(z)|$ in terms of the maximum of $|f|$ on the $2R$ circle and conclude

Comment: I don't, can you provide a reference?

Comment: The wikedia article  on entire functions has the formula ($\limsup \frac {n \log n}{-\log |a_n|}$); pretty much any book on entire functions (Boas, Levin are some classics) have its easy deduction